Yarn Dependency Issue with Node Version 6.14.2
I'm facing a roadblock with a project that is based on Node.js and compiles with Gulp. I'm trying to update the Yarn dependencies, but when I run yarn install, I get an error message saying that I'm using Node.js version 6.14.2, which is not compatible. However, my environment indicates that I'm using different Node.js versions. I've tried using Node.js versions 16, 13, and 20, but nothing seems to work.
Here's a summary of what I've done so far:
Checked Node.js Version: Verified that my environment is using the correct Node.js version.
node -v
Updated .nvmrc File: Ensured that the .nvmrc file specifies the correct Node.js version.
echo "16" > .nvmrc
cat .nvmrc
nvm use 16
Checked Environment Variables: Made sure there are no environment variables enforcing Node.js version 6.14.2.
echo $PATH 
Removed Conflicting Files: Deleted package-lock.json, yarn.lock, and the node_modules directory.
rm -rf node_modules rm -f package-lock.json yarn.lock
Cleaned Yarn Cache: Cleaned Yarn’s global cache.
yarn cache clean
Updated package.json: Ensured that the package.json file specifies the correct Node.js version.
Reinstalled Dependencies: Tried reinstalling the dependencies using Yarn.
yarn install
Despite all these efforts, I still get the error that Node.js version 6.14.2 is being used. I even suspected it might be a browser-sync compatibility issue but that wasn't the case. I'm stumped as to why Node.js 6.14.2 is being referenced when my environment isn’t set up that way. Is there a specific file or configuration that could be mandating this?
I've also attached an image of the error below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
(https://i.sstatic.net/QscZGaXn.png)

My first guess would be that it's not node or nvm doing the wrong thing, but how you installed the yarn package. Try npm instead to confirm?
